# Combining multiple Regex

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-urls

im looking to combine multiple regexes using a AND condition. For example, the following words should not be matched (starting of string):

```
database
audit
index
analysis
extract
good
bad
```

The strings that start with these strings will not be matched. Similarly, words such as others, error will be matched.

I have done a regex that is able to filter for each word but has not been successful at filtering out the list of words to be not matched.

```
#This will only match those that do not start with database    
r'(^((?!database).+)'
```

While trying to combine, it has failed to check both conditions.

```
r'(^((?!database).+)(^((?!audit).+)))'
```

Note: This regex is to be used in the django framework, urls.py file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to filter out strings which start with words in your negative list, then use a negative lookahead at the start of the pattern with an *alternation* to cover that list of words:

```
^(?!database|audit|index|analysis|extract|good|bad).*$
```

If you wanted to check for positive matches, or wanted a more complex pattern, then you may replace `.*` with the appropriate logic.

### Demo